# Editar Structured Type

Tags: sql, sql-server

Que tal alguien sabe si un structured type de sql puede ser editado para añadir mas campos ?

```
CREATE TYPE TablaActividadRealizada
AS TABLE(intAGRActividadRealizadaKey INT,
intAGRActividadLink INT,
intAGRSubActividadLink INT,
vchActividad VARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: Entiendo que no, solo haciendo un drop y creándolo nuevamente, y si ya lo estás usando en algún SP o función, deberás modificar previamente estos para que apunten al nuevo TYPE.

Comment: Ok muy bien, muchas gracias amigo ni hablar, queria evitar todo el rollo de crear uno nuevo jeje